# paintComponent with graphics

Tags: java, image, swing, graphics, jframe

I'm trying to create a `JFrame` with 1 image and a text box. I've managed to figure out the text box, but I can't figure the image painting. So far I have this:

```
public class Patcher extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -431324639043295668L;
private JPanel contentPane;

private static JTextArea textArea;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Patcher frame = new Patcher();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Patcher() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 319);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    textArea.setBackground(new Color(240, 240, 240));
    textArea.setText("123");
    contentPane.add(textArea, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    Image img = ImageIO.read(new URL(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("Icon_Entrey_21.png"), "img"));
    ImageObserver imgobs;
    panel.paintComponent(Graphics.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null));
    }
}
```

The idea is that I create a `JPanel`, declare an `Image` using a `ClassLoader` and try to draw it using `paintComponent()` method with `Graphics` as an argument. What am I doing wrong here?

Also I've tried creating a `new Graphics()` but that throws an error, as well.

Comment: Please, show the stackTrace.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg here are the compiler errors:
- The method paintComponent(Graphics) in the type JComponent is not applicable for the arguments 
  (boolean)
 - Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method drawImage(Image, int, int, ImageObserver) from 
  the type Graphics
on line 72.

Comment: 1) `drawImage` is now static method, you cannot run it just from `Graphics` (there should be some instance of Graphics); 2) it returns boolean, where JComponent::paintComponent requires Graphics as a parameter.

Comment: Not much help, try actually looking at the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should never explicitly call the  `paintComponent` method of any component. If you want to do custom painting, then you would instead create a custom class that extends `JPanel/JComponent` and `@Override` the `paintComponent` method. See more at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

   ```
   JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
       @Override
       protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
           super.paintComponent(g);
           g.drawImage(...);
       }
       // also override getPreferredSize()
   };
   ```
2. The easiest, and probably more correct, solution is just to use a `JLabel` and an `ImageIcon` instead of trying to custom painting.

   ```
   Image img = ImageIO.read(new URL(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("Icon_Entrey_21.png"), "img"));
   JLabel panel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
   contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
   ```

Comment: So, if using step 1 I create a class create a `JPanel` there and override `paintcompoent`, but how do I then implement the class? by `new classname().paintComponent(g)`?

Comment: You don't _have_ to create a custom class. Just use an anonymous class like I did in the example. Then `add(panel, ...)`. Unless you have more complex painting, then you _should_ create a custom class. `class ImagePanel extends JPanel`. Then `add(new ImagePanel(), ...  )`. But like I said, if all you want to do is paint an image, you're better off using a label and ImageIcon

Comment: Read the tutorial I linked, if you want to learn custom painting